# Mod Rewrite rules for a subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-config

I have a drupal installation set up in a subdirectory of a domain (www.mydomain.com/cms), but I'm having trouble getting the queries to format correctly using mod_rewrite. I need url requests coming in as:
{domain}/cms/admin/content/node
to be interpreted as:
{domain}/cms/?q=admin/content/node

Here's what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(cms/.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms/?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where these rules you posted are located? If you create a .htaccess inside the "cms" directory with the following content, I believe it should work fine:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```